# If in ajax successfull doesnt work

Tags: javascript, ajax, if-statement

I have a script that will check a file, then the file returns 1 or 0. But even if it returns 1 the script alert the else.
Why does this dont work?

When i alert txt it show 0 but when the txt is 1 the alert(txt) gives me 1.

So my question is, why does not hi! comes up when txt is 1?

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){ 
        //code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.    
        var txt = '';
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "checkfolder.php",
         success: function(result) {
             txt = result + '';
             if (txt == "1"){
                 alert("Hi!");
             }
             else{
                 alert(txt);
             }

         }
     });
 }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Most likely there's a line break before or after. This is one of the reasons why using alert for debugging is a bad idea. Try `console.log(result)` and `console.log(result.length)` and look in the browser's JavaScript console.

Comment: maybe use for result parseInt(result) if expect 1 or 0 and compare with integer not string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use parseInt so if u have any whitespaces form server response it would parse "1 " or " 1" to integer, 0/1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
    //code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.    
    var txt = '';
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "checkfolder.php",
     success: function(result) {
        if(parseInt(result) == 1) {
            alert('1');
        } else {
            alert('0');
        }

     }
 });
}, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try txt.trim()
I think there is problem with spaces.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var txt;
    $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
    //code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds.    
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "checkfolder.php",
     success: function(result) {
         txt = result;
         if (txt === "1")
         {
             alert("Hi!");
         }
         else{
             alert(txt);
         }

     }
 });
 }, 5000);
 });
```

Comment: Could you explain why making the variable global would magically make it work?

Comment: Please upvote if it worked... Mainly tell me why you are appending text='' for every iteration ?

Comment: It's not my question. Appending an empty string coerces the variable to a string so that it can be safely compared to a string. Your code is *even more likely* to not work because you've remove that part.

Comment: In AJAX response you always get the response in the String format, there is no point in converting it to string again, if i am not wrong. So were you trying to covert from string to string ??

Comment: **It's not my code**. If it does nothing, why would removing it help anything?

Comment: Actually, globalizing the variable has nothing to do with this, anyway text was inside the ready function. I removed it just to be in the safer side, since you were appending it to the response unnecessarily. "===" is comparison of same string with same type, so I made that change.

Comment: I think you are running the file on localhost, where you might have run the HTML file directly, which might have caused " Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes:....." error, and that's why you didn't get anything. Just run your HTML file from browser, "localhost/path/checkfolder.php". That will always work. If you still face any problem ping me  nsbhat44@gmail.com.